# what I am doing wrong with my adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, oncreate

I am trying to do a simple spinner with with 4 options, I create an adapter and set it to the spinner, but when I test it with the android emulator just appear the next error:

```
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{economico.mx.uv/economico.mx.uv.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at economico.mx.uv.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-06 00:43:56.948: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  ... 11 more
```

This is my code:

```
package economico.mx.uv;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Spinner criterioBusq;
private EditText camBusq;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        camBusq=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.camBusq);
        criterioBusq=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.criterioBusq);
        String []opciones={"Campus","Facultad","Nombre","Cargo"};
        ArrayAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, opciones);
        criterioBusq.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, so thank you beforehand for read it.

Comment: make sure you have `Spinner` with `criterioBusq`  id in `activity_main` layout

Comment: Are you sure your `EditText` and `Spinner` belong to `activity_main` layout?

Comment: you have an error on `criterioBusq.setAdapter(adaptador);` so make sure you have `criterioBusq` on `activity_main`

Answer (score 0):

Do not load the fragment first as its always get your `Bundle` null first so it will always load the `PlaceholderFragment` and then it will go for finding the `EditText` and your other views which are obviously not in your `PlaceholderFragment` layout file. So it will throw the nullpointer error.

Try out as below:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       camBusq=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.camBusq);
        criterioBusq=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.criterioBusq);
        String []opciones={"Campus","Facultad","Nombre","Cargo"};
        ArrayAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, opciones);
        criterioBusq.setAdapter(adaptador);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```